# Ajax post internal server error

Tags: ajax, post

This is my controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createTeam(string teamName)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true});
    }
```

And this is my js:

```
   $("#createTeamBtn").click(function () {
    var teamName = $("#TeamName").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Start/createTeam",
    data: teamName,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Textstatus: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

});

When i debugg it teamname above the ajaxpost gets the right value, but when it reaches the controller the value is null. The ajax post error writes internal server error, What is the problem?

Comment: Post the stack trace from the server. What framework are you using? Apache click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your data in a key/val pair:

```
var teamName = { teamName : $("#TeamName").val() };
```